# Rest - json-ld api method to calculate value?

Tags: rest, e-commerce, api-platform.com

I'm using json-ld api, schema.org and I follow convention: https://schema.org/DeliveryChargeSpecification
so I have:

GET /api/delivery_charge_specification
with params:

```
areaServed
weight
basketPrice
basketPriceCurrency
...
```

to return object with fields:

```
appliesToDeliveryMethod
price
priceCurrency
weight
basketPrice
basketPriceCurrency
```

and front end will be processed many records to get the only one. But this is one way. Front end doesn't like it. The thing is that we need delivery price and this depend on many params(could be even product_id etc.).

What if I do action:

POST /api/delivery_charge_specification
with params:

```
areaServed
weight
basketPrice
basketPriceCurrency
```

and as result I will have only:
    price
    priceCurrency

The problem with that is, if I follow json-ld I should create second resource and as result have resource:

GET /api/delivery_charge_specification/3234

and this return:

```
price
priceCurrency
```

Have anybody idea how this should be done to have satisfied front end and json-ld concept?

Comment: You may create some Entity classes with the [Schema Gen Component](https://api-platform.com/docs/schema-generator/). In case you wonder what to do with the Entity classes, you could start with following the api branches of [my tutorial](https://github.com/metaclass-nl/tutorial-api-platform). For getting started and required knowledge see the readme. Calculating a delivery price will probably be somewat like a report, see chapter 9.